# Kotlin list all activities at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a simple debug activity that allows me to start any activity of my project at runtime.

As of right now, I've implemented a RecyclerView which gets its data from a list, in such fashion:

```
    val activitiesList = ArrayList<Activity>()
    activitiesList.add(FrameHomeActivity())
    activitiesList.add(LeaderHomeActivity())
    activitiesList.add(LoginActivity())
    ...
```

but this relies on me having to manually update this list when adding a new activity.

I've already managed to attach a clickListener to the RecyclerView, so that each activity can start successfully when an item is touched.

Is there a way to get all the activities in the project "dynamically", so that I don't have to update this code each time a new activity is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call constructor of an Activity instead you fire an `Intent` . You get the `Activity` from `PackageManager` then you start it by name.

```
val activities = packageManager
        .getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities
    val nameList= activities.map { it.name }
```

`nameList` here is `List<String>` it will contains fully qualified name of your Activity classes .
You can use this name to create an `Intent` to start the activity from adapter.

```
fun onClickItem(context:Context, activityName:String){
            try {
                val c = Class.forName(activityName)
                val intent = Intent(context, c)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all activities using this code

```
getActivity()
  .getPackageManager()
  .getPackageInfo(getActivity().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
  .activities
```

Edit - getActivity() can be replaced by this when calling from activity else when calling from fragment getActivity() will be required.

Comment: Thanks, but this retrieves a list of ActivityInfo. Is there a way to retrieve an Activity from an ActivityInfo object?

Comment: From Activity Info you can get all information about an Activity including the exact package name which can then be used to launch / list the activity

Comment: Also the fact in the code you have pasted you are creating activity objects by yourself which is wrong instead you should keep a list of Activity.class or the exat intents that you would need to launch the activity.